# Is there a difference in LESS to include classes inside header tag?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

In my less-file, I have a section where I define some responsive code for my navigation.

I want to use this style only for the header, otherwise it will affect my footer too. But my site doesn’t show  the styled navigation if I wrap it in `header`. This doesn’t work:

```
header {
    .content {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }

    li.expanded.dropdown {
        float: none !important;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        float: right !important;
        background: #b4b48e;
        width: 160px;
        margin: 0px -15px;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

But this works:

```
.content {
    padding-top: 80px;
}

li.expanded.dropdown {
    float: none !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float: right !important;
    background: #b4b48e;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0px -15px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
}
```

What am I missing?

Compiled non-working version of the CSS, including HTML:

```css
header .content {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
header li.expanded.dropdown {
    float: none !important;
}
header .navbar-nav {
    float: right !important;
    background: #b4b48e;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0px -15px;
}
header .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-default container" id="navbar" role="banner">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="/startseite" title="">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="">
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <div class="region region-navigation-collapsible">
      <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-bootstrap-custom-main-menu-menu" id="block-bootstrap-custom-main-menu" class="contextual-region">
        <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
          <li>some navigation</li>
          <li>there are more items here</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Should it be `.header`? As in is the `header` a CSS class or HTML element?

Comment: Where is your tag with with `content` class? It's not part of the header so obviously won't work when you add the header at the start

Comment: Also your `navbar-default` class is part of the header tag itself so also wont work

Comment: @CalvT this solved it. had to include navbar-default behind header. thanks a lot.  i am blind like a bat. if you want to write an A i will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS shows the `navbar-default` class as a sub element to the header, when in fact it is a class of the header itself. So by changing your CSS to the following it should work.

```
header.navbar-default {
    .content {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }

    li.expanded.dropdown {
        float: none !important;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        float: right !important;
        background: #b4b48e;
        width: 160px;
        margin: 0px -15px;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color:white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for (something more like) this below, but as commented, your markup simply does not "match" your css.

```
header.navbar-default {

li.expanded.dropdown {
  float: none !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
   padding-top: 80px;
   float: right !important;
   background: #b4b48e;
   width: 160px;
   margin: 0px -15px;
}

 .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color:white;
 }
}
```